# Django ViewDoesNotExist error

Tags: python, django

I have just migrated to a different OS and after copying my perfectly-fine-working django project across I have been faced with the `ViewDoesNotExist` error when trying to load the admin page.

I removed the line in my `urls.py` file that points to the offending view function but then django just complains about the view that the url above it is pointing to, so I removed that, no joy :( . I ended up removing all the projects urls apart from the `logs` url to get it to run the admin page

```
Environment:

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/admin/

Django Version: 1.4
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.admindocs',
 'south',
 'uni_form',
 'treebeard',
 'dojango',
 'item',
 'letter')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'clientms.middleware.EnforceLoginMiddleware',
 'dojango.middleware.DojoCollector')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in wrapper
  213.                 return self.admin_view(view, cacheable)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  91.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  89.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  196.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  89.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in index
  353.                             model_dict['admin_url'] = reverse('admin:%s_%s_changelist' % info, current_app=self.name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse
  447.                 app_list = resolver.app_dict[ns]
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in app_dict
  290.             self._populate()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _populate
  253.                     for name in pattern.reverse_dict:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse_dict
  276.             self._populate()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _populate
  265.                 lookups.appendlist(pattern.callback, (bits, p_pattern, pattern.default_args))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in callback
  216.         self._callback = get_callable(self._callback_str)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in wrapper
  27.         result = func(*args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in get_callable
  101.                     (lookup_view, mod_name))

Exception Type: ViewDoesNotExist at /admin/
Exception Value: Could not import letter.views.import_uploader. View does not exist in module letter.views.
```

`setting.py`

```
# Django settings for clientms project.

import os

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)

# TODO: replace all case of 'if something:' with 'if something is None:'

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
    'NAME': 'xxxx',              # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
    'USER': 'xxxx',         # Not used with sqlite3.
    'PASSWORD': 'xxxx',     # Not used with sqlite3.
    'HOST': 'localhost',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
    'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}

SITE_URL = 'http://localhost:8000'

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# On Unix systems, a value of None will cause Django to use the same
# timezone as the operating system.
# If running in a Windows environment this must be set to the same as your
# system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/London'

COUNTRY_CODE = '+44'
USER_VARIABLES = 'bool1','bool2','bool3','bool4','bool5','int1','int2','float1','float2','float3','date1','date2','string1','string2'
# TODO: this should be used with the item history for 'client', 'file', 'alarm', 'communication' and 'letters' in the item view
SHORT_HISTORY_LENGTH = 5
LETTER_EDITOR_HEIGHT = 400  # Height of the editor for letters and templated letters

# TODO: Make sure english dates work when deployed (???)

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-gb'
#DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ('%d-%m-%Y','%Y-%m-%d')

SITE_ID = 1
SITE_ROOT = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = False

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale
USE_L10N = True
NUMBER_GROUPING = 3
THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = ','
USE_THOUSANDS_SEPARATOR =True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = ( os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'static/files'))

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = SITE_URL+'/files/'

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = ( os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'static/static'))

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# URL prefix for admin static files -- CSS, JavaScript and images.
# Make sure to use a trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://foo.com/static/admin/", "/static/admin/".
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    #( os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'static/static')),
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    # Common
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    # Session
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    #'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    # Authentication
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    # Mesages (deep phython I think!)
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Force Login
    'clientms.middleware.EnforceLoginMiddleware',
    # Dojango Form stuff
    'dojango.middleware.DojoCollector',
)

LOGIN_URL = '/log/in/'

PUBLIC_URLS = (
    r'log/in/',
    r'admin/',
    r'static/',
    r'dojango/dojo-media/',
    r'dojango/test/',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'clientms.urls'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    '/home/arthur/Software/django/clientms/login/templates',
    '/home/arthur/Software/django/clientms/ajaxuploader/templates',
    '/home/arthur/Software/django/clientms/item/templates',
    '/home/arthur/Software/django/clientms/letter/templates',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'south',
    'uni_form',
    'treebeard',
    'ajaxuploader',
    'dojango',
    'item',
    'letter',
)

# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
    'mail_admins': {
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
    }
    },
    'loggers': {
    'django.request': {
        'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'propagate': True,
    },
    }
}
```

`urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'clientms.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^clientms/', include('clientms.foo.urls')),
    url(r'^$', 'page.views.main_view'),
    url(r'^settings/', include('clientms.page.urls_settings')),
    url(r'^countries/$', 'page.views.test_countries'),
    url(r'^home/$', 'page.views.home_view'),
    url(r'^item/', include('clientms.item.item_urls')),
    url(r'^letter/', include('clientms.letter.urls')),


    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    #url(r'^dojango/', include('dojango.urls')),
    # Logs you in and out of the app
    url(r'^log/', include('login.urls')),
)

# DEVELOPMENT ONLY !!!
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Why would django complain that it can't find ANY views in a project? (and it's not a permissions thing [chmod])

EXTRA: NOTHING in the error page points to any of my files (just django `core`,`contrib`,`views` and `utils`)

EXTRA!: On a different note when I load `localhost:8000` I get

```
[21/May/2012 17:55:43] "GET /static/messages/messages.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[21/May/2012 17:55:43] "GET /static/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[21/May/2012 17:55:43] "GET /static/jquery-1.7.2.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[21/May/2012 17:55:43] "GET /static/ajaxuploader/js/fileuploader.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1697
[21/May/2012 17:55:43] "GET /static/ajaxuploader/css/fileuploader.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1703
[21/May/2012 17:55:43] "GET /dojango/dojo-media/1.6.1/dojo/dojo.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3424
[21/May/2012 17:55:43] "GET /dojango/dojo-media/1.6.1/dojango/dojango.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3442
[21/May/2012 17:55:43] "GET /dojango/dojo-media/1.6.1/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css HTTP/1.1" 404 3472
[21/May/2012 17:55:43] "GET /dojango/dojo-media/1.6.1/dojo/resources/dojo.css HTTP/1.1" 404 3457
[21/May/2012 17:55:43] "GET /dojango/dojo-media/1.6.1/dojox/form/resources/FileInput.css HTTP/1.1" 404 3490
[21/May/2012 17:55:43] "GET /dojango/dojo-media/1.6.1/dojo/dojo.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3424
[21/May/2012 17:55:43] "GET /dojango/dojo-media/1.6.1/dojango/dojango.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3442
[21/May/2012 17:55:43] "GET /static/ajaxuploader/js/fileuploader.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1697
[21/May/2012 17:55:43] "GET /static/ajaxuploader/css/fileuploader.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1703
```

All the folders have the same permissions so I don't know why it would load some static files and not others

Comment: Post some code and the error message / stack trace.

Comment: Is your PYTHONPATH set to include your django project?

Comment: Also, is `import_uploader` defined in your `letters.views` module?

Comment: jid: Yup! The project was working fine till I had to update my ubuntu

Comment: Replace that `localhost` output with a snippet of your settings.py and your urls.py

Comment: I think you missed mentioning that you have an extra factor here. You have this dojango app you are using to refer to your `admin/' while I had thought you meant the standard django admin view. You should try maybe stripping back these extra apps and dependencies until you can get the vanilla django admin view working right. Then starting turning stuff back on. Its really difficult for any of us to know what the problem is if there are too many custom factors in your setup.

Comment: I don't know where you got the idea that `dojango` was pointing at `admin/`. Dojango is just a way of intergrating the dojo js framework with django's form.

Comment: @jdi: I removed all my apps but one and then replace all the view function contents with `pass` and still no avail :(

Comment: Would you be able to update the tracebacks now that you have thinned out the configuration? Your `/admin/` traceback still shows that it depends on a custom view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one thing I can think of is the folder structure which is changed in Django 1.4,If you are coming from Django 1.3,ensure absolutely that you delete /usr/local/bin/django-admin.py when uninstalling 1.3 before you install 1.4.
    I faced a similar problem with munged folder structure and wrong python paths due to conflicting installs.
    A slightly dirty solution I did was to create a new project in 1.4 then copy over the files from  the older install into the new folder structure,except for the new manage.py which I left in it's position.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the only difference here is your environment. Your static media would continue to load because its relative on the filesystem and django knows where to look (same with templates). Its dynamic (or referenced explicitly in your settings.py)

What you are probably missing is your django project in your PYTHONPATH

```
export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/django/project:$PYTHONPATH
```

Comment: I tried that and unfortunately nothing changed. Same error and the statics still won't load :(

Comment: @Sevenearths: Something in your path might be wrong though. Because the error is telling you that `import_uploader` doesn't exist in `letters.views`. Can you confirm that it does? Could it be finding another view that does not contain this definition?

Comment: @Sevenearths: Are you now running on django 1.4 vs previously using 1.3?

Comment: @Sevenearths: The project should work the same as long as you are using the original manage.py and didn't start using the 1.4 manage.py version, without fixing your project structure.

Comment: I pulled over everything but the database. I had to run `manage.py syncdb` under 1.4